# Error compiling PostGIS 3.1 from source : "undefined reference to `GEOSIntersectionPrec'"

Tags: postgis, compile

I am just trying to build the new PostGIS 3.1.0 (with GEOS 3.9.0). But I consistently get an error about "undefined reference to `GEOSIntersectionPrec'".

The commands I used was (*which was successful with PostGIS 3.0.x, but not with 3.1.0{,alpha3,beta1,rc1}*):

```
wget https://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-3.1.0.tar.gz
tar xf postgis-3.1.0.tar.gz
pushd postgis-3.1.0
./configure --with-geosconfig=/opt/geos/bin/geos-config --with-sfcgal=/opt/sfcgal/bin/sfcgal-config
make
```

The error says:

```
...
---- Making all in loader
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/src/postgis-3.1.0/loader'
/bin/bash ../libtool --mode=link \
  gcc -I ../liblwgeom  -I/opt/geos/include   -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/opt/sfcgal/include -I/usr/include/json-c  -DNDEBUG  -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -fno-math-errno -fno-signed-zeros  -fPIC -DPIC    shpopen.o dbfopen.o getopt.o shpcommon.o safileio.o shp2pgsql-core.o shp2pgsql-cli.o ../liblwgeom/liblwgeom.la -o shp2pgsql -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -L/usr/lib/llvm-9/lib  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5 -Wl,--as-needed -static ../liblwgeom/liblwgeom.la  -lc
libtool: link: gcc -I ../liblwgeom -I/opt/geos/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/opt/sfcgal/include -I/usr/include/json-c -DNDEBUG -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -fno-math-errno -fno-signed-zeros -fPIC -DPIC shpopen.o dbfopen.o getopt.o shpcommon.o safileio.o shp2pgsql-core.o shp2pgsql-cli.o -o shp2pgsql -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z -Wl,relro -Wl,-z -Wl,now -Wl,--as-needed  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/llvm-9/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5 ../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.a -lm -L/opt/geos/lib -lgeos_c /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so -ljson-c -L/opt/sfcgal/lib -lSFCGAL -lc
/usr/bin/ld: ../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.a(lwgeom_geos.o): in function `lwgeom_intersection_prec':
/home/user/src/postgis-3.1.0/liblwgeom/lwgeom_geos.c:710: undefined reference to `GEOSIntersectionPrec'
/usr/bin/ld: ../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.a(lwgeom_geos.o): in function `lwgeom_unaryunion_prec':
/home/user/src/postgis-3.1.0/liblwgeom/lwgeom_geos.c:788: undefined reference to `GEOSUnaryUnionPrec'
/usr/bin/ld: ../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.a(lwgeom_geos.o): in function `lwgeom_difference_prec':
/home/user/src/postgis-3.1.0/liblwgeom/lwgeom_geos.c:840: undefined reference to `GEOSDifferencePrec'
/usr/bin/ld: ../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.a(lwgeom_geos.o): in function `lwgeom_symdifference_prec':
/home/user/src/postgis-3.1.0/liblwgeom/lwgeom_geos.c:891: undefined reference to `GEOSSymDifferencePrec'
/usr/bin/ld: ../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.a(lwgeom_geos.o): in function `lwgeom_union_prec':
/home/user/src/postgis-3.1.0/liblwgeom/lwgeom_geos.c:1044: undefined reference to `GEOSUnionPrec'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:108: shp2pgsql] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/src/postgis-3.1.0/loader'
make: *** [GNUmakefile:22: all] Error 1
```

All the components had worked with PostGIS 3.0.x versions. I had the same error with 3.1.0alpha3/beta2/rc1 and thought this might an issue with a development version. But now the released version seems to give the same error.

*Does anyone know how to fix the error?*

(This is under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause seems to be that the Makefile in PostGIS-3.1.0 did not include the link options for custom a geos package.

The problem is fixed by editing `loader/Makefile` and then appending the following GEOS link options

`-L/opt/geos/lib -lgeos`

to line 25 that looks like:

`CFLAGS= -I ../liblwgeom  -I/opt/geos/include ...`

-- Update --

Another option/flag, which seems more relevant for PostGIS-3.1.4, is to add a new line (after the `CFLAGS` line above) using `LDFLAGS`:

```
LDFLAGS= -L/opt/geos/lib -lgeos
```

This seems to solve linking errors that cannot be solved using `CFLAGS`.

Answer (score 1):

A duplication of `libgeos` libraries can produce such error.

The same error happened to me, when I've tried to compile postgis on another server, with a custom geos build. I've built geos, but when I was trying to build postgis, I've got the same error.

#### The solution

Check if any other libgeos libraries exist.

```
ldconfig -v 2> /dev/null | grep libgeos
    libgeos.so.3.10.0dev -> libgeos.so.3.10.0dev
    libgeos_c.so.1 -> libgeos_c.so.1.15.0
    libgeos_c.so.1 -> libgeos_c.so.1.13.1
    libgeos-3.8.0.so -> libgeos.so
```

Since there were other libgeos libraries around, let's see where they come from.

```
dpkg -l | grep libgeos
ii  libgeos++-dev                               3.8.0-1build1                                                 amd64        Geometry engine for GIS - C++ development files
ii  libgeos-3.8.0:amd64                         3.8.0-1build1                                                 amd64        Geometry engine for Geographic Information Systems - C++ Library
ii  libgeos-c1v5:amd64                          3.8.0-1build1                                                 amd64        Geometry engine for Geographic Information Systems - C Library
ii  libgeos-dev                                 3.8.0-1build1                                                 amd64        Geometry engine for GIS - Development files
```

Remove those packages:

```
sudo apt remove libgeos-dev libgeos-c1v5 libgeos-3.8.0 libgeos++-dev
```

#### Compile postgis

postgis should find and use a custom libgeos build without any options set.

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make -j8
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

The culprit was an earlier attempt to install postgresql with postgis (packages `postgresql-13-postgis-3` and `postgresql-13-postgis-3-scripts` have to be removed).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

CFLAGS= -I ../liblwgeom  -I/usr/local/include/geos   -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/include/json-c  -DNDEBUG  -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -fno-math-errno -fno-signed-zeros  -fPIC -DPIC  -L/usr/local/lib  -lgeos